# Как вытащить первое значение

Tags: python, bs4, request

Всем привет, от bs4 получаю вот такую вот строку `<span>372<sup>60</sup>`, как мне вытащить только значение 372?
Здесь 372 это цена а 60 это копейки, если просто вытаскивать find('span').text то он выдает вот так 37260, а нужно разделение
Подскажите плиз

Comment: вы просите text вам и дают текстовый ответ, а надо поработать со span

Comment: да, но в теге span есть тег sup, он его тоже забирает, я не могу разобраться как именно мне вытащить только span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

span.contents даст список содержимого, разбитый по тэгам, вам нужен первый элемент

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
text = '<span>372<sup>60</sup></span>'
span = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml').find('span')

print(span)                         # <span>372<sup>60</sup></span>

print(span.contents)                ['372', <sup>60</sup>]

print(span.contents[0].strip())     # 372
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!!!